# Sonar Runner - How to export issues to MS-Excel

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to export sonar issues into Excel by using sonar-ws-client. Its exporting successfully. However it is exporting different project instead of my project. I want to export specific project.

```
String login = "admin";
    String password = "admin";

    SonarClient client = SonarClient.create("http://localhost:9000");
    client.builder().login(login);
    client.builder().password(password);

    IssueQuery query = IssueQuery.create();
    query.severities("CRITICAL", "MAJOR", "MINOR");

    IssueClient issueClient = client.issueClient();
    Issues issues = issueClient.find(query);
    List<Issue> issueList = issues.list();
    createExcel(issueList);

private static void createExcel(List<Issue> issueList) {
...
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact web service queries you're using.

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding project name like below,

```
IssueQuery query = IssueQuery.create();
query.componentRoots("Your_Project_Name");
```